# Cannot insert NULL value to the PostgreSQL table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I'm using Spring's **JpaRepository** to perform a named SQL query:

```
public interface ManagerRegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<ManagerRegistration, Long> {

    // jpa-named-queries.properties
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    void insertWithoutConflict(@Param("phoneNumber") Long phoneNumber,
                               @Param("clientId") Integer clientId,
                               @Param("createdAt") LocalDateTime createdAt);

}
```

There is a native SQL query in **jpa-named-queries.properties**:

```
ManagerRegistration.insertWithoutConflict = \
INSERT INTO manager_registrations \
       (phone_number,  client_id,  created_at) \
VALUES (:phoneNumber, :clientId,  :createdAt) \
   ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

It works correctly if I make all parameters non null. But there is a problem if I try to make **clientId** equal to **null**:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "client_id" is of type integer but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How do I insert a record to the PostgreSQL table with NULL parameter using native query?

This is table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE manager_registrations (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    phone_number int8 NOT NULL,
    client_id int4 NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT manager_registrations_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Can you show the table definition please? It seems like your table definition doesn't allow null values at all.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I've added table DDL

Comment: Based on the table definition, phone_number can not be null if that is the one you are trying to save as null that is the reason for the error. I would try to log the parameters and the generated query because the error statement is weird, it is saying the attribute value in client ID doesn't match the definition of the table although it is an integer...

Comment: edit: I make clientId equal to NULL